# Is there any timer that fires at specified times in Apache Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I can use quartz2 and cron job in Camel to kick start a route every n hours. Is there a way  (or endpoint?) that I can specify exactly at what times of the day I want it to fire? like 10:00, 12:00, 14:00 and 20:00.

Hope the question is clear, if not, let me know and I'll explain further.

Kind regards,

R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah silly me it was actually very easy:

```
0+0+10,12,14,20+1/1+*+?+*
```